# Create a animated rectangle in WebGL

Tags: html, webgl

i want to create a animation in WebGl, my idea is like this:

- You inside a large rectangle.
- The sides of this rectangle are animated with image of a binary gif.
- The camera is going forward until infinity.

I want to create like this image in WebGl:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0GpT.jpg

But i don't know, how do put the camera inside a large rectangle and going the camera to forward until infinity, someone can help me?

Comment: Can you tell us how much experience you have with WebGl? How do you normally program WebGl related code? For instance do you use any helper libraries like THREE.JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what the author called "nano-Doom" :-)  It has a few planes which make up a world, and you can move the camera around with the keyboard:

http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?p=1067

Given the little information you provided in your question, my suggestion would be to run through the preceeding lessons up to the one given above.